# Find the nearest set of points in 3d space

Tags: 3d

I have a set of 4 cuboids which are defined by 8 coordinates. The cuboids are grouped as follows (front view)

[Front view of cuboids](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZeSz.jpg)
So, each of these cuboids has coordinates as shown in the table below:
[Coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lR6Z5.png)
Basically, I want to be able to catch the coordinates that are marked in yellow. These coordinates define the 'empty' space, defined by 8 points, that is being created within the 4 cuboids.

What I have done so far, which seems to work, is to:

1. calculate the center point by taking the average off all X,Y and Z coordinates.
2. calculate the deviation from each X,Y,Z to its average in absolute terms
3. multiply those deviations for combination of X,Y,Z over X,Y,Z respectively ($\Delta_X*\Delta_Y*\Delta_Z$)

The 8 points with an identical outcome are the ones that are the closest to the center point and allow me to select the right coordinates. I don't fully understand though why this works and whether or not it will scale up to a shape which looks like this in front view:
[shape with 5 boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpBzd.jpg)

You can assume that all shapes are always adjacent to each other.
Axis are defined as follows:
Y
|
|
.----- X
/
Z

Comment: For me, the significance of the first set of coordinates in the Excel table isn't clear 1) What is represented in "front view" is in (y,z) axis with $x$ (not represented) the depth ? 2) Are these coordinates the bottom left vertex coordinates of each rectangle/cuboid ?

Comment: Actually, when trying to find the type of coordinate system I am using, I also found the solution to my issue. What I basically need is the Euclidean distance...